# Where is the bug in this react web app footer?

Tags: reactjs

When I try to compile my app locally, it doesn't run. It must be a really simple bug, but I can't seem to find it. I'm also not an experienced programmer, so the answer will seem very obvious. Thank you for any help!

Here is the code:

```
import React from 'react';

import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

import twitterIcon from './twitterIcon.svg';
import facebookIcon from './facebookIcon.svg';
import './Footer.css';

const Footer = () => (
  <div className="Footer-wrapper">
    <div className="Footer-text-links-wrapper">
      <Link to="/about">
        <span className="Footer-text-link">About</span>
      </Link>
      <Link to="/faq">
        <span className="Footer-text-link">FAQ</span>
      </Link>
      <Link to="/contact">
        <span className="Footer-text-link">Contact</span>
      </Link>
      <a href="xxx"><span className="Footer-text-link">Community</span></a>
    </div>
    // <div className="Footer-icon-links-wrapper">
    //   <a
    //     href="https://www.twitter.com"
    //     target="_blank"
    //     rel="noopener noreferrer"
    //   >
    //     <img src={twitterIcon} className="Footer-icon-link" alt="twitter" />
    //   </a>
    //   <a
    //     href="https://www.twitter.com"
    //     target="_blank"
    //     rel="noopener noreferrer"
    //   >
    //     <img src={facebookIcon} className="Footer-icon-link" alt="facebook" />
    //   </a>
    //
    // </div>
  </div>
);

export default Footer;
```

Here is the error per the terminal:

```
Failed to compile.

./src/components/Footer/Footer.js
Syntax error: Unexpected token (40:2)

  38 |     //
  39 |     // </div>
> 40 |   </div>
     |   ^
  41 | );
  42 |
  43 | export default Footer;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can't place `//` comments in jsx. https://wesbos.com/react-jsx-comments/

Answer (score 0):

Comments cannot be like `//` as in Javascript inside JSX. To write comments you can do something like this `{/* ...comment */}. So in your code it will look something like

```
    </div>
{/* <div className="Footer-icon-links-wrapper">
        ...
   </div> */}
  </div>
```